# Firefox WebExtension - chrome.tabs.query

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I do this:

```
var a = 'moz-extension://c5b86449-4457-4a39-a758-958faf23fc72/popup.html'
chrome.tabs.query({ url: a }, function(x){});
```

I get an error:

```
Invalid match pattern: 'moz-extension://c5b86449-4457-4a39-a758-958faf23fc72/popup.html'
  SingleMatchPattern()   MatchPattern.jsm:49
  this.MatchPattern()    MatchPattern.jsm:103
  self.tabs.query()      ext-tabs.js:556
  callAsyncFunction()    Extension.jsm:422
  inject/stub()          Schemas.jsm:1002
```

However, that is the URL that I need to match on in the `chrome.tabs.query` call.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) suggests `moz-extensions` is **not** a valid scheme in a matching pattern

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX. That is likely the issue. `moz-extensions` is still in beta.

Comment: @GlenLittle I update my answer, I hope this helps you.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Thank you. I may not be able to confirm the answer for a while, but it looks good!

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox v48 the error message no longer appears, however the `moz-extension:...` protocol is not yet supported.

`chrome.tabs.query` returns `0` in `x.length` if search like this `"url": "moz-extension:..."`, see example:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ url: "moz-extension://..." }, function(x){
    console.log(x.length);
});
```

But there is an alternative way to get around the problem, you can search by all tabs without "url:" param, see the following examples:

### Get tab data:

```
function getTab(pageFromAddon, callback)
{
    var uri = chrome.extension.getURL(pageFromAddon);

    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        var tabData;

        if (tabs && tabs.length) {
            for (var i = tabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (tabs[i].url === uri) {
                    tabData = tabs[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        callback(tabData);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
//get id, url, title and other info from tab (or false)
console.log(getTab("view/page.html"));
```

### Open or refresh tab:

```
function openOrUpdateTab(pageFromAddon)
{
    var uri = chrome.extension.getURL(url);

    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        var tabId;

        if (tabs && tabs.length) {
            for (var i = tabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (tabs[i].url === uri) {
                    tabId = tabs[i].id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tabId) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { "active": true });
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({ "url": uri });
        }
    });

    return uri;
}
```

Usage:

```
//If openned refresh tab, if not create new tab
var id = openOrUpdateTab("view/page.html");

//get url from new or refreshed tab
console.log(url);
```

### Important note

For using these functions you need add `"tabs"` to `permissions:` (`manifest.json`) like this:

```
    ...

    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```